# VLC player event catch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vlc

In my C# application i need to trigger some events when a VLC player (preferably) starts playback (a play button is pressed in VLC for example).Tried Windows Media Player classic with Microsoft Spy++  and observed messages that are sent when playback starts\repeats but i don't know how i could "catch" those messages in my C# code.So my question: is there any way to hook up to event in VLC (or WMP) and get notified about playback status (play, stop, start of repeat).

My goal is to create a C# function that waits for start of playback event in player and then triggers some actions in my application (this should also happen when playback ends and starts repeating). What approach should i take here?

Just to clearify: I don't want to embedded a new instance of VLC in my app, but instead control/read the "real" full version of VLC, started seperatly by the user

Comment: I put a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586257/activex-vlc-player-events-are-not-working

Answer (score 1):

The below linked article looks like it is old, but maybe you can glean some good info from it if not use the component outright.

[.NET Interface to VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/.Net_Interface_to_VLC)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to control the full one you'll probably have to use the telnet interface or the web interface