# ActiveX VLC Player events are not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, activex, vlc

[I have incorporated **ActiveX VLC pligin to WPF application**.](http://zahidakbar.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/using-the-vlc-activex-control-in-wpf/) And VLC Plugin is working fine.

```
AxVLCPlugin   vlc = new AxVLCPlugin();
vlc.MediaPlayerEncounteredError += vlc_MediaPlayerEncounteredError;
vlc.MediaPlayerOpening += vlc_MediaPlayerOpening;
vlc.MediaPlayerBuffering += vlc_MediaPlayerBuffering;
vlc.MediaPlayerEndReached += vlc_MediaPlayerEndReached;
 //
// Other code 
// like    windowsFormsHost1.Child = vlc; and etc
vlc.addTarget(videoURL, null, AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListReplace, 1);
vlc.play();
```

But some how all events of VLC are not working at all.

I mean these events:

```
vlc.MediaPlayerEncounteredError += vlc_MediaPlayerEncounteredError;
vlc.MediaPlayerOpening += vlc_MediaPlayerOpening;
vlc.MediaPlayerBuffering += vlc_MediaPlayerBuffering;
vlc.MediaPlayerEndReached += vlc_MediaPlayerEndReached;

 void vlc_MediaPlayerEndReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("[P] - StreamingVideo -  END REACHED + " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        void vlc_MediaPlayerBuffering(object sender, DVLCEvents_MediaPlayerBufferingEvent e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("[P] - StreamingVideo -  BUFFERING + " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        void vlc_MediaPlayerOpening(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("[P] - StreamingVideo -  OPENING + " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        void vlc_MediaPlayerEncounteredError(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("[P] - StreamingVideo -  ERROR + " + DateTime.Now);
        }
```

They are not firing. (Sure, I put breakpoints in those methods.)

What I really need is catch the streaming errors and re-apply *videoURL* another time. So I am experimenting with events to  see which of them I can use to reach that goal.

Any clue why is it?

P.S. This link doesn't help also [VLC player event catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911088/vlc-player-event-catch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong. It seems; those events are not implemented (or unimplemented) for some reason (even in the latest version of the activeX). I've [**read**](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=77515&start=20) that those events are either too buggy or not firing at all in some browser plugin versions too.

However, it still has 3 useful and working events you can count on.
**Events Firing:** `playEvent`, `pauseEvent` and `stopEvent`
**Events Not Firing:** all events starting with `MediaPlayer`...

Anyway, code below works with the events I mentioned:

```c#
    AxVLCPlugin vlc;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vlc = new AxVLCPlugin();
        windowsFormsHost1.Child = vlc;

        vlc.pauseEvent += new EventHandler(vlc_pauseEvent);
        vlc.playEvent += new EventHandler(vlc_playEvent);
        vlc.stopEvent += new EventHandler(vlc_stopEvent);
    }

    void vlc_playEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("playEvent fired!");
    }

    void vlc_pauseEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("pauseEvent fired!");
    }

    void vlc_stopEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("stopEvent fired!");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (ofd.FileName != "")
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ofd.FileName);
            vlc.addTarget("file:///" + ofd.FileName, null, AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListReplaceAndGo, 0);
            vlc.play();
        }
    }
```

Still, these events will not inform you about any streaming errors. IMO, only thing you can do is; try-catch where you execute `vlc.addTarget(...)` and `vlc.play()`. Check whether the URL is valid beforehand (also don't forget to include `"file:///"` infront of the file path with the recent versions of the plugin). And re-apply the videoURL (as you like) only if the caught error is not about non-existing file or invalid path, etc.

**OR** you could try some other wrappers/custom libs:

- [VLC DotNet for WinForm & WPF](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/)
- [More at this page](http://wiki.videolan.org/C_Sharp)

Comment: I think you are right at this moment and may be yes they will implement those events in the later version of VLC ActiveX. So u won +++

Comment: Also it seems VLC ActiveX is a dead project as well and I am guessing because of the H.264 standard take his leader role.

Comment: is it possible to bind a running instance of VLC to this activeX control ?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be something like this:

```
vlc.MediaPlayerEncounteredError += new MediaPlayerEncounteredErrorEventHandler(vlc_MediaPlayerEncounteredError);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on VLC from Design → Properties → Event (Thunder Icon) → Select `axVLCPlugin21_MediaPlayerend` at `MediaPlayerEndReached`.

See an image for more details:

[image]